# ggplot boxplot: log10 y axis AND forced 0-100 range

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I'd like to plot some data histogram-style.  The data is scaled so that one single observation has a value of 100.  ***However, the data will be broken up by category into separate sections of a document, so the maximum value of most groups will not be 100.***

I'd like my plots to use a ***log10 y axis***, and to have use a ***fixed 0 to 100 scale***.

The following honors the log transformation, but ignores the 0-100 range with a warning.  I have tried other permutations of  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 100))  and scale_y_continuous(trans = log10_trans()), with no luck yet.

```
library(ggplot2)

toread <- "general  specific    satisfaction
fruit   apple   9
fruit   apple   8
fruit   banana  8
fruit   banana  7
fruit   pear    6
veg carrot  7
veg celery  4
veg turnip  3
veg turnip  2
veg turnip  1
grain   pasta   6
grain   quinoa  3
grain   brownrice   2
grain   brownrice   6" 

foodprefs <- read.table(textConnection(toread), header = TRUE) 
closeAllConnections() 

foodprefs$pct.max <- (foodprefs$satisfaction / max(foodprefs$satisfaction)) * 100

lapply(sort(unique(
  as.character(foodprefs$general))), function(one.cat) {

    temp <- foodprefs[foodprefs$general == one.cat , ]

    ggplot(temp, aes(x = specific, y = pct.max)) +
      geom_boxplot() +
      ylim(0, 100) +
      scale_y_log10() +
      coord_flip()
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has two problems:

1. Invoking `ylim()` establishes a scale for the y-axis, which is why you get the warning about specifying a second scale (the log scale), which will overwrite the first. This is why your ylims weren't "sticking".
2. `log10(0)` = Infinite, which cannot be plotted, so that limit is invalid for the log scale function.

As an aside, your code can be simplified with the *plyr* package. The following code uses `scale_y_log10` to specify the limits, and solves both problems. Additionally, the use of *plyr* makes the code cleaner.

```
library(plyr)
dlply(foodprefs, .(general), function(one.cat) {

    ggplot(one.cat, aes(x = specific, y = pct.max)) +
        geom_boxplot() +
        scale_y_log10(limits = c(1, 100)) +
        coord_flip()
})
```

[image]

I'm not sure that a log scale makes for a great visualization here, but there you go.